# Manga where the (female) main character is summoned with another girl, trains with knights for a few weeks, and is sent away

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I would be grateful if anyone can tell me the title.

It was a summoning with another girl, where the other girl wants to send her away.
She ends up getting some survival skills with one of the knight groups, before getting sent to a house in the middle of a demon forest. She gets injured on her way to the house, and the old/previous demon king finds her and helps her to the house. I remember she cooks food for the wild animals/beasts. Also the leader of the knights and one of the mages comes and visits her often. I think it was a transport scroll.

She becomes an adventurer, and the king who sent her to die in the forest tries to recruit her. She uses wolf familiars as adventuring buddies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the MC's hair?

Comment: Someone has attempted to edit this question to indicate that the manga in question is black & white. If that person is you, Ell, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, you can regain access to the account by following the instruction provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Doing so will enable you to edit the question yourself, leave comments within this thread (like this one), and mark a corrected answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as per the [tour].

Comment: Is this a manga where two girls are summoned as the saint(ess); it's really the MC but the other girls takes credit/is mistaken for the saint(ess)? There's a few with that basic premise, but I haven't found any where she becomes an adventurer or has wolf familiars. You might want to try searching manga sites (e.g. anime-planet) for recommendations of some of these, e.g. "I Was Summoned to Be the Saint, but I Was Robbed of the Position, Apparently"